# Vb.net problems download

Tags: vb.net

How can I do a check that first download something and only after that it starts up the *program.exe*?
I already tried to do something like this but it excutes the file when the download is not finished and it throws some errors.
my Code:

```
Dim client As WebClient = New WebClient
Dim SourcePath As String = "C:\ProgramData\KDetector\UserAssistView.exe"
Dim SaveDirectory As String = "C:\ProgramData\KDetector"
Dim FileName As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(SourcePath)
Dim SavePath As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(SaveDirectory, FileName)
If System.IO.File.Exists(SavePath) Then
    Process.Start("C:\ProgramData\KDetector\UserAssistView.exe")
Else
    client.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri("http://ge.tt/70n8YPr2"), "C:\ProgramData\KDetector\")
    Process.Start("C:\ProgramData\KDetector\UserAssistView.exe")
End If
```

Comment: can you provide us with code sample that have the problem

Comment: As Muhammad said, provide us with a snippet in order to explain what you did and help us to understand you problem. I really suggest you to read [how to create a good example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before asking another question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the asynchronous `DownloadFile` method. Asynchronous method will not block the calling thread.

In order to avoid the problem, your code must be like this:

```
    Dim downloadLink As String = "http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/userassistview.zip"
    Dim saveFilePath As String = "C:\ProgramData\KDetector\userassistvkew.zip"
    Dim fileName As String = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(saveFilePath)
    Dim client As WebClient = New WebClient
    Try
        CheckExsist(saveFilePath, fileName)
        'Before was client.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri("http://ge.tt/70n8YPr2"))
        client.DownloadFile(downloadLink, saveFilePath)
        MsgBox("Download file completed. File saved in: " & saveFilePath)
        'Zip extraction stuff
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

This is the CheckExsist sub:

```
Private Sub CheckExsist(ByRef sourcePath As String, ByVal fileName As String, Optional ByVal counter As Integer = 1)
    If System.IO.File.Exists(sourcePath) Then
        sourcePath = sourcePath.Replace(Path.GetFileName(sourcePath), "") & fileName & "(" & counter & ")" & Path.GetExtension(sourcePath)
        counter += 1
        CheckExsist(sourcePath, fileName, counter)
    End If
End Sub
```

I manage to download the software (from the official website) and save it as a .zip. Code the last few rows to programmatically extract the .zip, if you ecounter any problem or bug feel free to ask with another question. Anyways there are alot of post on SO regarding zip extraction on vb.net

Comment: Yes, now it downloads the program but the original size is 30 kb and the downloaded (that is in the SourcePath) file's 3 kb and result is that the application can not be started. Some ideas? Thanks alot.

Comment: @Lorenzo because you are downloading the HTML page and saving it like a .exe

Comment: @Lorenzo answer edited in order to achieve your goal. `Zip extraction` snippet is missing because I'm working on .Net3.5 and alot of usefull tools are compatible only with newest version of the framework

Comment: I'm not going to suggest you any function that i cannot test, hope my answer will help you now ;)

Comment: Thanks, i'll try. There is a problem in third line, Path is not declared.

Comment: where? because it  was working perfectly during my test

Comment: Ok works, and how can i do to startup the program.exe that is into zip archive?

Comment: 1) extract the zip. 2) run the .exe. I cannot test the zio extraction code because I'm on winXP with .net3.5 at the moment

Comment: What's wrong with: Dim zipPath As String = "C:\ProgramData\KDetector\userassistview.zip"
        Dim extractpath As String = "C:\ProgramData\KDetector\"                       ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, extractPath)

Comment: Did you add the correct reference? you have to link the .dll and add the reference (importing the .dll is not autoreferencing).
The reference is: `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll`

Comment: This is the error: variable object or variable With block not set

Comment: @Lorenzo I highly suggest you to ask another question. This question is supposed to help you to download the file from an url + I cannot help you with compression and decompression because i cannot test it. I don't want to look greedy but, can you accept my answer if statisfies you and ask another question about zip problem? 
You will also get more attention from users with a brand new question.